# scraping with python using bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to **scrape** from

url in code : [url](https://live.batstream.tv/?sp=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,25&fs=13px&fw=700&tt=none&fc=405115&tc=333333&bc=FFFFFF&bhc=FDFDFD&pd=4px&mr=1px&tm=817503&tmb=FFFFFF&wb=e5e5e5&bsh=0px&rdb=FFFFFF&rdc=C74300&l=https://sport-play.tv/register/&lt=1&lsp=1&lcy=1&lda=1&l2=https://sport-play.tv/register/&l2t=1&l2sp=1&l2co=1&l2cy=1&l2da=1)

I trying to get from there to a dictionary ,
`{key (name of game) : value (list of links)}`
now when Im trying , i cant find the div tag with the **id=accordion** .
and because of this Im stuck now :
my code:

```
def findLiveGamesInBetman():

    dic = {}
    links = []
    url ='https://live.batstream.tv/?sport=football&sp=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,25&fs=13px&fw=700&tt=none&fc=405115&tc=333333&bc=FFFFFF&bhc=FDFDFD&pd=4px&mr=1px&tm=817503&tmb=FFFFFF&wb=e5e5e5&bsh=0px&rdb=FFFFFF&rdc=C74300&l=https://sport-play.tv/register/&lt=1&lsp=1&lcy=1&lda=1&l2=https://sport-play.tv/register/&l2t=1&l2sp=1&l2co=1&l2cy=1&l2da=1'
    # Fetching the html
    request = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    content = urlopen(request).read()
    parse = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    body=parse.find('body')
    div_con = body.find('div', {"class": "container"})
    div_row = div_con.find('div', {"class": "row"})
    div_col = div_row.find('div', {"class": "col-lg-12"})
    div_accor = div_col.find('div',{'id' : 'accordion_t'})
    div_ac = div_accor.find('div',{'id' : 'accordion'}) #--> this return empty
```

note : the url in this code is the but it just the games.
I had been looking here to find something that may help , but unfortunately,I didnt find anything.
how can I fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: yes, because there is no division tag with id="accordian"

Comment: TNX , So how can I scraping this html and get this links?    Sombody has a solution ?

Comment: can you give a sample output?

Comment: yes, if u enter the web you saw a lot of h2 headres , so i want to take the tag div in the h2 with class :match , this text will be the name of the game , after this to find al href in the a tag and to enter them into list.[link](https://i.imagesup.co/images2/7c39e3513283843527ff7e22cf09392307e78326.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, now that I see what you were trying to scrape, I can tell you what is the problem. The element that you are trying to scrape, only loads after client side JavaScript is executed. Only a browser can load it. "requests" on its own, doesn't execute JS on a website. So for what you want, you would need Selenium and as your user-agent is Mozilla so geckodriver. After that you can do your normal bs4 stuff.

Comment: OK , tnx . So if I understand what you meant,I need with the selenium to find this tag by xpath or css selector , and after to take this href by a tag with bs4? I hope this will do the job